# Coveralls not working with Appveyor

Tags: code-coverage, appveyor, coveralls

I have used 'appveyor tool' for building project and 'coveralls tool' for code coverage. my `appveyor.yml` file is like below. While executing the command the following error is thrown.

> "Bad response: 422 {"message":"Couldn't find a repository matching
>   this job.","error":true}** Command exited with code 1".

```
version: 1.0.{build}
pull_requests:
do_not_increment_build_number: true
configuration: Release
platform: Any CPU
environment:
  COVERALLS_SERVICE_NAME: appveyor
  nodejs_version: "0.10"
  COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN:
  secure: 6tdds8x61Nm9X9NRdsdsd+hlU0iEyo8g+457eAJTisdhK14SERTfdfS7vsdOp1et+h
build_script: xyz
build:
project: .\Slack.Automation\Promact.ERP.sln
parallel: true
verbosity: minimal
test_script:
 - npm test
after_test:
 - node ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js < ./coverage/lcov.info
```

So please give any solution.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that message **Couldn't find a repository matching this job** means that you are using token which is not tied to any repo in Coveralls.

Please try to do the folowing (assuming you are using GitHub):

1. Add your repo to Coveralls using https://coveralls.io/repos/new if you did not add it before
2. Open https://coveralls.io/github/your_account/your_project/settings and copy `REPO TOKEN`
3. Encrypt this token with https://ci.appveyor.com/tools/encrypt and replace secure value of `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` with this new encrypted value

--ilya.

Comment: Does it work if you do it locally, without appveyor?

Comment: I wonder how to encrypt this token. You need to copy token you got from coveralls and paste in to https://ci.appveyor.com/tools/encrypt under your account. And only after that use it in YAML. Thus it will be encrypted with your private key and decrypted properly during build time.

Comment: Actually it's not working in locally also when I used encrypted private key, It throws the error like "Couldn't find a repository matching this job". When I used non-encrypted value it's working fine.

Comment: If you use tool from command line, don't use encryption, for appveyor - use encrypted value for COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN.